# Drupal: Possible to assign view permissions to all cck fields for a node type?

Tags: drupal, permissions, cck

I've created a custom content type: product

This product has an image (cck file field) and a few other cck fields that make up it's content definition.

By default, when an anonymous user looks at a published product, they do not have permission to view the image or any other cck field.

Personally, I don't really want to have to always go in and alter the permissions for each individual field that belongs to the node.

Is it possible to set the permissions at the node level and have it cascade down to the individual fields? I've tried a few different modules that set node level access.. but I believe that is all they do. They don't actually drill down into the fields.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "node", do you mean "Content Type"? (e.g. "...belongs to the node", "...set the permissions at the node level...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the "content permissions" module. You probably have it enabled right now. By default all fields will be visible if the node is accessible to the end user (after you disable the module).

Comment: I think the OP wants to set permissions for fields per Content Type, not per node. So he'll need some sort of permissions module.

Comment: @greg: He does *not* want to set permissions for fields: "Personally, I don't really want to have to always go in and alter the permissions for each individual field that belongs to the node." I suspect he has enabled the content permissions module by default. He simply needs to disable that module.